# Incorrect regex assignment

Tags: java, regex, brackets, parentheses

I'd like my regex to assign these and only these values: 1a, 1b, 2a, 2b, 3a, 3b, n. It seems that my regex is not working: "[([1-3][a-b])(n)]". Why it doesn't "see" the round bracket containing [1-3][a-b] and how should this regex look to work correctly?

Comment: Outer brackets ruined your regex completely. Try `s.matches("[1-3][ab]|n")`. Do you mean you want to match a string equal to `n` as one of the alternatives? Or `2n`, `1n`?

Comment: Just n. But removing the outer brackets helped and now it's working correctly! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: So, you want to match `1an`? `([1-3][a-b])(n)` will match `1an`, `3bn`... I mean, just removing outer square brackets won't help I think. Did you mean my regex above worked?

Comment: It worked just fine :)

Comment: Then please consider accepting my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like my regex to assign these and only these values: `1a`, `1b`, `2a`, `2b`, 3a, `3b`, `n`.

That means, you need to use

```
.matches("[1-3][ab]|n")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XUXGMy/1)

In your pattern, the outer square brackets created a character class and the inner ones just were treated as [unions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) and the whole `"[([1-3][a-b])(n)]"` matched just 1 char (a `(`, or `1` to `3` digit, or `a` to `b` letter, etc.